# Find second class of a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to find second class of a div with first class `gifv-player`, in my case `divone`  I tried like this :

```
var test = $(".info-div .gifv-player").attr('class');
```

but the result is `gifv-player divone` and not only `divone`?

```
        <div class="ifo-div" >
        <div class="gifv-player divone" >
        <p> Div 1 content</p>      
        </div>
        </div>
         ...
```

any help?

Comment: I don't understand your question.There are no classes inside div `gifv-player`, only a paragraph.

Comment: @DavidLi sorry i mean the second class, the class after this 'gifv-player'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is the way you can get the second class of the div:

```
<div class="gifv-player divone" >
        <p> Div 1 content</p>      
        </div>

$(".gifv-player")[0].classList[1] // returns divone
```

be aware, the class `divone` always must be in second position.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".gifv-player").attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

By calling attr('class'), you are pulling all the classes the element is a part of, separated by spaces. You can split that output and grab the second class every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var classList = document.getElementsByClassName('gifv-player').className.split(/\s+/);
      for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
   if (classList[i] === 'divone') {
    //do something
   }
```

}